# Value Error converting an object to a float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using a dataset which has a column "price" with values as "$150.00". In order to remove "$" I used:

> `df.price = ([x.strip('$') for x in df.price])`

It worked. However, this column still remain as an "object". So  my next step was check the highest values to identefy any value greater than "1000.00", that might be represented as "1,000.00. I used:

> `print((df["price"]).sort_values(ascending=False))`

and it returned top list highest value as "999.00".

Then I tried to convert the `object` column "price" as a `float`. I used:

> `df['price'] = df['price'].apply(np.float)`

But it returned:

> **`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2,000.00'`**

Beside the column do not present any number greater than 999.00. I tried to remove any "," using:

> `df.price = ([x.strip(',') for x in df.price])`

Then I tried again:

> `df['price'] = df['price'].apply(np.float)`

But the same error has returned
**`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2,000.00'`**

I dont know what's happening and what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Because it is still text, `"2,000"` is technically smaller than `"999"` when sorted as text.

Comment: How are you reading the data in originally?

Comment: Have you tried coercing the entire column to float?  df['price'].astype("f").  I can't see your input dataframe but I think it would have coerced the string example you give above ('2,000.00").  You can then format it using various format strings.

Comment: `strip()` only removes characters at the beginning or end of the string. You want `replace()` since the comma is in the middle of the number

Comment: @user1558604 It is a csv file from [Inside AirBnB](http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data.html) a lisitngs.csv.gz .

Comment: @leeprevost I was using the strip function in a wrong way. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @G.Anderson that was my mistake. Thank you it helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `strip` only removes characters from both left and right ends of a string, a `,` is in the middle, consider using `replace` instead, something like this should work:

```
df.price = ([x.replace(',', '') for x in df.price])
```

And then turn them into `floats`.

Comment: Great, it woked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with an apply:

```
df1.Value.apply(lambda x: np.float(str(x).replace(',','')))
```

Comment: @paulorayner i'm glad it worked for you. Check out: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235  and thanks again. Welcome to stackoverflow!